# How do I upgrade apt and lib*?

Tags: apt, upgrade, libreoffice

When Ubuntu 16.04 updated some weeks ago, Libreoffice crashed almost instantly. Removing and reinstalling from the Ubuntu software centre did not help. The error report was sent to Ubuntu, but nothing happened:

```
Sorry Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error" mentioned
somewhere that an " unreportable reason"  You have some obsolete
package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages and
check if the problem still occurs. apt, apt-utils,libapt-inst2.0,
libapt-pkg5.0,
libdrm-amdgpu1,libdrm-intel1,libdrm-nouveau2,libdrm-radeon1,libdrm2,libgl1-mesa-dri,libgl1-mesa-glx,libglapi-mesa
```

How do I upgrade these packages? Obviously Ubuntu have not done this, and I am a novice at Linux.

The hardware is X86 so it's 32-bit.

Comment: Just use the update manager.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install apt apt-utilslibapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libdrm-amdgpu1libdrm-intel1libdrm-nouveau2libdrm-radeon1libdrm2libgl1-mesa-drilibgl1-mesa-glxlibglapi-mesa
```

If any of these packages need to be upgraded the third command will upgrade the obsolete version packages to the current version. Otherwise the third command will do nothing if all the packages are already the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a terminal : `sudo apt update`

Any errors displayed ?

If not, then : `sudo apt upgrade`

Then try installing the problematic packages :

`sudo apt install apt apt-utilslibapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libdrm-amdgpu1libdrm-intel1libdrm-nouveau2libdrm-radeon1libdrm2libgl1-mesa-drilibgl1-mesa-glxlibglapi-mesa`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.
This problem was solved in the following way:
I found that there is sudo upgrade app on my computer. It needed an update itself first. 
Next I ran this app, and the error message disappered.